# Get all device's model names connected to Wi-Fi in Android

Tags: java, android, ip-address, android-wifi, mac-address

I need to get information of all the devices connected in a single Wi-Fi. I've already got all connected device's IP addresses, MAC addresses and Company names. But I still can't get the model or hostnames of the connected devices. Is it possible to do so? How?

If it's not possible, then is there a way to get the device model or hostname from the IP address or the MAC address?

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct API that provides wifi client's information. But you can read `/proc/net/arp`. this file has information about client details. also, you have to add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Details like connected IP address, HW type, flag(connection status), Mask, HW address, device

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/net/arp")));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String info = line.split(" +");//info array have information on each index, access it like info[ 
    }
    br.close();
}catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```

flag **0x2** : Device connected
flag **0x0** : Device not connected (If device is disconnected it will not removed from the file)

Comment: I already got the connected devices IP and MAC. But, I want to device model name.

Comment: You will get device name.